# Is there a verb meaning depthify (getting more depth)?

Tags: single-word-requests

One of the meaning of *depth* is *profundity*. That is the sense I mean in the following title.

> Chinese Protests Get Depth.

I mean that the protesters use methods that are more profund, meaningful, and thoughtful, compared to similar protests in the past.

Is there another verb to use instead of ‘get depth’?

Comment: I don't think English has a verb specifically encapsulating the sense ***be more profound than** [something less sophisticated]*.

Comment: depth and profundity are not synonyms, fyi. Are you trying to write a headline?

Comment: Gain substance.

Comment: Or even just "grow"

Comment: What's wrong with "deepen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intensify**

Deep is a bad word to describe a protest.  Saying a protest got deeper is bad English. As a native speaker I do not understand what you are trying to say -- especially with no examples.

A good word is *Intensify*. For example

> The protest began as an online survey on Reddit. But by the end of the month it **intensified** into active civil unrest. For example hunger strikes, large crowds blocking tanks with their bodies, or burning all British cloth in the country.

Deepen is often used with the noun sentiment. For example a headline might be

> Protests Intensify as Anti-British sentiment deepens.

Answer (score 20):

How about this...

> **deepen**
> *transitive verb*
> : to make deep or deeper
> *intransitive verb*
> : to become deeper or more profound
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deepen)

Comment: Yup. That's the one I thought of, too. Now, _shallow_ is another matter.

Comment: This answers the title, but not the example. If I read that the protests had deepened I would think more people were involved or more instances of protest occurred, but not that they were more sophisticated. I don't think there is a single word that fits this abstruse concept.

Comment: @David Yes, 'deepen' ≈ 'become more entrenched', _not_ = 'become more sagacious/erudite'.

Comment: @David I think the example is different to what's being asked anyway - there, the word "get" seems to be used to mean the protests _acquire_ a depth where they previously had none, rather than to _increase_ the depth they already had.  If it were the latter, then "deepen" would be appropriate.

Comment: For me, if protests deepen, it suggests to make that there is more emotional, or perhaps more violence involved. I don't think this is what the author wants to convey.

Answer (score 1):

"Heighten" carries the connotation of increased amount or  degree.

> (SOED) **heighten** make high or higher; give or add height to; *fig.* increase or augment in amount or degree.

I think that neither  "Chinese protests get depth." (sounds unidiomatic),   "Chinese protests deepen" or "Chinese protests heighten" are statements bearing on the *methods* being used; instead they have to do  with the nature of the protests. ([protest methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22protest%20methods%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

- Chinese protest methods heighten.

Comment: Well, then, be very careful of which metaphors you use. Up and Down are both relevant to a gravitational field, but social usages are quite different.

Comment: If we like, we can similarly make other dimensions into metaphors: not only *deepen, heighten*, but also *widen, lengthen*.

Answer (score -2):

**methodical**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methodical

> arranged, characterized by, or performed with method or order